# My computer keeps freezing. I cannot reinstall or reset the OS. What can I do?

Tags: windows, windows-10, freeze, crash, reset

**Background**

My computer freezes often. I am using Windows 10, most recent updates. It does not blue screen, it does not shut down, it just freezes. The windows I had open stay open, I can move my mouse, but nothing else works. It seems random - I cannot identify any causes or commonalities relates to the error.

I assumed the easiest way to solve this would be to reset the system completely with a clean reinstall of the OS. Everything is backed up, so that's not an issue. However, both the built in "Reset this PC" option and reinstalling from an ISO file both fail. I suspect the freeze might be occurring during the reset and causing it to fail, but cannot verify this.

**My question**

How can I correct, or at least diagnose, the issue?

**Update**

To be perfectly clear, it works a lot of the time, but after a while it just freezes. I am using it as we speak with no problems. When it is not freezing there is no slowdown or anything.

**Update 2**

Running ScanDisk on my main drive does not reveal any errors. I did this in an attempt to verify the theory proposed by commenters that my HDD was at fault.

Comment: Remove as many HW parts as you can. Just MB/CPU/cooling/1xRAM. Does it work or does it freeze is you try to boot from USB? Add a HDD, run SMART check. Try again, does it fail with the HDD? ... Etc etc.

Comment: When you say that *"reinstalling from an ISO file"* failed, how so?  Did you try deleting all of the partitions first?

Comment: If you can move your mouse around, that means your computer isn't frozen, it just means its waiting on HDD I/O.  replace the hdd

Comment: To clarify, it works fine for quite a while before freezing sometimes. I am posting from it right now. But when it feezes, it will stay that way indefinitely. Commenters so far seem to be assuming it is a hardware problem and nothing something with the OS. I'm not disagreeing, but is there any particular reason for that assumption?

Comment: @Ramhound if it is the HDD that is fine, why does it work a large percentage of the time? Again, not disagreeing, just trying to understand. Why do you think that it must be a hardware and not a software problem?

Comment: @Run5k No I did not try deleting the partitions. Won't that make it totally unusable if the reinstall does indeed fail? When you ask "How So?", I just double clicked the ISO on my desktop and launched setup.exe and went through the UI flow.

Comment: The majority of your sectors are fine, it only has problems, when a file on a bad sector is read.

Comment: @Ramhound ok. and is there any way to verify that that is actually what is happening? are there any alternative explanations that i should look into before just buying a new hdd?

Comment: Understood.  When I hear *"installing from an ISO,"* I typically think that they are actually using an optical disc.  Ultimately, that may be your best bet:  [creating a USB or DVD](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO/) to delete all of the existing partitions and perform a fresh install of the operating system.

Comment: Yes;  There is a way to verify it.  What does your research say?

Comment: @Ramhound My research says to use the scandisk utility, which indicates that no errors were found. Given that, do you still suspect the HDD?

Comment: @Run5k But that will still fail if it is a hardware problem right? Is there any way to verify that it is indeed an OS problem before I go that route and wipe out everything?

Comment: Yes, it could potentially fail if there is a lingering hardware error.  You can help [verify the integrity of the operating system](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/bd832f07-1420-0c14-d2a5-0a5a24ba40be/using-system-file-checker-in-windows-10) by opening an elevated command prompt and executing **sfc /scannow**

Comment: Run a linux live OS (or install linux) and see if the error presents.

Comment: @user657451 I can't reinstall Windows, what makes you think I could install Linux?

Comment: Because windows is crappy software and linux is not.

Comment: @user657451 You have failed to understand the problem. The issue is not with the software I'm installing. It doesn't matter whether linux is better than windows (for the record, I agree that it is better). I will not be able to install any OS because my system freezes during the process.

Comment: @Run5k I ran it and the first time the system froze during execution so I didn't get a result, but the second time it said no issues were found. So that means that there are no hardware problems and that I should reinstall the OS? Or is it the opposite?

Comment: so you detemined that it is a hardware problem then  -_-;

your statement was that "Windows 10 freezes..." and that Windows methods of remedy fail. So remove windows from the equation, and see if the error (freezing) persists in another environment. Linux will also give you much more useful debug information.

Comment: You said that you scanned the hard drive already:  did you execute `CHKDSK /F C:` ?  If not, it would be a good idea to try that next.

Answer (score 0):

After months of dealing with this, I finally took it somewhere to get it fixed.

Interestingly, most of the commenters were wrong. It had nothing to do with my hard drive.

It was an issue with the OS installation. Reimaging the machine fixed it. However, reinstalling the OS directly would not work, as the freeze would occur during the reinstall. It was necessary to apply a new image using Dism / Windows PE or similar.

Comment: If a computer is freezing *during* an OS installation, that almost certainly points to a hardware problem.  That will be cool if the problem is genuinely gone, but I remain skeptical.

Comment: @CharlesBurge Problem has been gone for a week now when before it was happening multiple times per day. I will update this again if the issue comes back, but I don't think it will

Comment: Can you define "reimaging?" Did they store an image to a secondary drive or network path and then put that image back on the same HDD? The thing is your description matches exactly with what happens with large areas of bad sectors, and the apparent "freezing" is just the retry process. This can take hours to recover from, and is the reason why @run5k suggested chkdsk with a full surface scan, fix and mark process. Scandisk does not do this. The marking process helps to allow the OS to avoid those sectors.

Comment: Pretty sure it was not an issue with the OS. Scandisk is not conclusive.

Comment: @jiggunjer ok... so given that i did not replace any hardware and the issue was fixed after reimaging, what do you think the problem was?

Comment: @Yorik they had a backup image and they reapplied it to the same drive

Comment: @nhouser9: all of this is speculation of course, but a bad block is only going to affect you if you try and access it and it is not flagged. If I had to guess blindly, I would say you had bad blocks in your pagefile or in random file which the OS used 10% of the time and sporadically. So your wipe and reimage may have put all your files in a different physical place on the drive platter and you are, currently not accessing those bad blocks. See for example: (http://askubuntu.com/questions/241944/how-to-fix-the-hard-drive-bad-sector/490552 )

Comment: p.s. you can accept your own answer, but maybe do a full surface scan in offline mode. I *think* `chkdsk c: /f /r` will do this and mark the blocks for you, but it may take many hours (overnight).

Comment: @Yorik I will do that before accepting the answer. Thanks =]

Comment: The windows installer applies an image similar to the winpe/dism method mentioned. I'm not sure about the true cause, all I know is that it is premature to call the commenters wrong.

Comment: @jiggunjer I am not sure why you say that... Commenters suggested the issue could only be fixed by replacing hardware. The issue is fixed... I did not replace any hardware.